# Convert list to dictionary with probability in each entity

Tags: python, list, dictionary, probability

So I have a list like this:

```
['2 ROOT S . ', '1 ROOT S ! ', '1 ROOT is it true that S ? ', '1 S   NP VP ', '1 VP  Verb NP ', '1 NP DT Noun ', '1 NP NP PP ', '1 PP Prep NP ', '1 Noun Adj Noun ', '1 Verb ate ', '2 Verb wanted ', '1 Verb kissed ', '3 Verb understood ', '1 Verb pickled ', '2 DT the ', '1 DT a ', '1 DT  every ', '1 Noun president ', '2 Noun sandwich ', '1 Noun pickle ', '3 Noun chief of staff ', '1 Noun floor ', '1 Adj fine ', '2 Adj delicious ', '1 Adj perplexed ', '3 Adj pickled ', '2 Prep    with ', '1 Prep on ', '1 Prep under ', '3 Prep    in ']
```

The numbers in front of each entity is the probability, the next string is the key of the dictionary, and the remaining string is a value of that particular string. What I need to do is extract each entity of the list and input it into a dictionary. For example for the first three i need to create a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
dict = {
'ROOT': [['2/4'], ['1/4'], ['1/4'], ['S', '.'], ['S', '!'], ['is', 'it', 'true', 'that', 'S', '?']]
}
```

ROOT is the key, first three values of are the probability of the last three values which would be picked randomly. There's probably a better way to structure the dictionary but i'm fairly new to python so i'm just picking all this up as I go.

Maybe possible some sort of nested dictionary if that's possible?
Thanks

Comment: Why are there some empty strings in the list? What is their purpose?

Comment: Im creating the list from a text file, im not sure why it creates empty strings but you could just ignore them.

Comment: @Eithos that isn't a concern, if it is for you, prior to your program, call `list = [item for item in list if item != ' ']`

Comment: @A.J.Well, I know that now...

Comment: pnizi np, @Eithos, glad to hear it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised no one's given this a shot. The following code does not perform exactly as the example you described, but is (in my opinion) a better way of expressing the data.

```
probabilityDict = {}
for i in valueList:
    if i != ' ' :
        y = i.split()
        typeKey = y[1]
        probabilityKey = y[0] + '/4'

        if typeKey not in probabilityDict:
            probabilityDict[typeKey] = {}

        if probabilityKey not in probabilityDict[typeKey]:
            probabilityDict[typeKey][probabilityKey] = []

        probabilityDict[typeKey][probabilityKey].extend(y[2:])
```

**Output**

```
print probabilityDict

  {'ROOT': {'1/4': ['S', '!', 'is', 'it', 'true', 'that', 'S', '?'], '2/4': ['S', '.']},
   'Adj': {'1/4': ['fine', 'perplexed'], '2/4': ['delicious'], '3/4': ['pickled']},
   # etc... }
```

In your example, `'1/4'` was repeated. Over here you can see the key is merged in order to hold all the values that match the given probability. The advantage of merging it this way is that you can now use it as a nested dictionary (as you asked about).

For example:

```
print probabilityDict['ROOT']['1/4']
>>> ['S', '!', 'is', 'it', 'true', 'that', 'S', '?']
```

I don't know where you plan to go from here, but keep in mind some useful `dict` methods that can help you. To get iterators (i.e to use in `for loops`), use:

```
# On Python 2x
probabilityDict['Root'].iterkeys()
probabilityDict['Root'].itervalues()
probabilityDict['Root'].iteritems()

# On Python 3x
probabilityDict['Root'].keys()
probabilityDict['Root'].values()
probabilityDict['Root'].items()
```

And keep in mind dictionaries are *unordered* data. You'll have to take this into account with the rest of your code.